# Getting error while calling Android method from Typescript

Tags: android, typescript

I am taking assistance from this: [Call Android method from TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220743/call-android-method-from-typescript)

I just want to pass a string in a function with a key so that when function gets called from Android device, it can consume that string.

typescript file:

```
declare var android: WebAppInterface;

interface WebAppInterface {
  showToast(toast: string): any;
}

buttonClicked() {
  android.showToast('Hello Android!');
}
```

So when I call this function, I am getting error as `ERROR ReferenceError: android is not defined` 
 and I think that is true, but not able to resolve this issue.

Here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3t8ee

Comment: @stud3nt Sorry. That doesn't help. Still getting the error.

Comment: Have you actually followed the instructions in your linked S/O answer on setting up "JS Binding"? Your `declare var` line is just asserting that the variable will be filled in with a value - it is up to the binding to actually inject that value. And FYI, that code is never going to work in StackBlitz or any desktop browser, because the whole point is that it is relying on the Android binding. You could use a fallback - `typeof(android)!=='undefined' ? android.showToast('Hello Android!') : alert('Hello Non-Android!')`